# How to Test an iOS Library Which Is Using UIKit

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uikit

I would like to create a library for iOS applications which uses UIKit. Furthermore I would like to create unit tests for this library. Unfortunately my tests do not work because of UIKit (`[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]` to be precise).

According to [Apple's Unit Testing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html) there are two types of test cases: logic tests and application tests. Application tests seem to be the correct type for tests involving UIKit related stuff but I did not find out about how to set up application tests for libraries. Has anybody ever had the same problem and was able to solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just ran into this, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: This question may be irrelevant. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/41404613/62 for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to this. You must add a new target to your project that is simply an empty application. Then use that application as your test host following the instructions for doing this with a regular application like here:

[Why does instantiating a UIFont in an iphone unit test cause a crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689586/why-does-instantiating-a-uifont-in-an-iphone-unit-test-cause-a-crash)