# How do I make XCode 4's logic unit tests properly initialize a UIViewController from a nib?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, unit-testing, xib

In XCode 4.2, I have some logic tests that I want to exercise against a UIViewController that loads itself from a xib when initialized. However, even though I've added all my xibs and images to the unit test bundle, whenever I try to run those tests i get the following error:

```
Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle
</Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Developer/usr/bin>
(loaded)' with name 'MyController'
```

Is there something I can do to force my tests to find the xibs and other resources in the proper place? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i needed to change my unit tests to Application Tests from Logic Tests. This post has some useful info on that:

[Why does instantiating a UIFont in an iphone unit test cause a crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689586/why-does-instantiating-a-uifont-in-an-iphone-unit-test-cause-a-crash/8810993#comment12673692_8810993)